# Error IJulia Install

Tags: julia

I have Ubuntu 14.04 , I've installed JULIA, and then I tried to install IJULIA, writting Pkg.add("IJulia") on julia, but this appears:

```
signal (4): Illegal instruction
_mapreduce at ./reduce.jl:168
prune_versions at ./pkg/query.jl:141
prune_dependencies at ./pkg/query.jl:335
jl_trampoline at /usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
jl_apply_generic at /usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
resolve at ./pkg/entry.jl:379
edit at pkg/entry.jl:24
jl_trampoline at /usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
jl_apply_generic at /usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
anonymous at task.jl:340
jl_trampoline at /usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: -1230846045)
unknown function (ip: -1230845923)
julia_trampoline at /usr/bin/../lib/i386-linux-gnu/julia/libjulia.so (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 134516370)
__libc_start_main at /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 134516419)
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

Do any one knows what to do? What I want to achieve is to run ipython notebook --profile julia

Comment: What version of Julia do you have?